# Why do I get runtime Error 3078 when using an imported table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database where I import a table in VBA then directly try to use that table and I get the Runtime error 3078 cannot find table "UserNew".

Imported table name is UserNew

The code is fairly simple:

```
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMARMC_USERS SELECT UserNew.* FROM UserNew;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
```

I think this is just happening so fast that the table doesn't register in the database before I try and run the SQL. When I get the error and go into debug step into the code runs.

How and I get the imported table to be immediately available for use in this SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as in debug mode it always works fine, you need to give the code a break:

```
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMARMC_USERS SELECT UserNew.* FROM UserNew;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
    DoEvents
```

Sometimes, using the WinApi "Sleep" you can better calibrate this timing:

Declare it at the top of the standard module you are using:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Call it on the code:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMARMC_USERS SELECT UserNew.* FROM UserNew;"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
DoEvents
Call Sleep(1000) '1000=1 sec.
```

Comment: Thanks! I did have a break built in that allows it to run. I was hoping for a different answer, but I guess I'll have to stick with the pause.

Comment: You can create a function to check if the table exists, and loop if it does not. That should probably work. Lots of "TableExists" functions in Internet.